# Is it possible to add a sub collection to a collection without creating document in firestore in android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to cloud firestore in firebase. In my project I created *category* as collection which is common to all users. But I need to create *category* as sub collection for each collection. Is it possible?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> It is possible to add sub collection to collection without creating document in firestore in android?

Definitely not! According to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model), the only structure that is permited is as follows:

```
db.collection('coll').doc('doc').collection('subcoll').doc('subdoc')
```

There is no way in Firestore to store a collection beneath other collection. So the following line of code is not allowed:

```
db.collection('coll').collection('subcoll').doc('subdoc') //Not allowed
```

As there is no way to store a document beneath other document.

```
db.collection('coll').doc('doc').doc('subdoc') //Not allowed
```

Comment: Update: you can now create sub-collections by adding a document to a path. E.g. you can create a collection reference to `root_collection/document/subcollection` where document doesn't exist. If you `coll_ref.add({}, doc_id)` that document will be created and can be fetched. The current problem is that you can't discover this collection through recursive document and collection streaming because the linking document is missing. This can make it easy to orphan sub-collections.

Answer (score 17):

The answer from Alex is mostly correct, except he doesn't point out that you can have a subcollection under a document that doesn't exist.  There is no obligation to have an actual document in order to have subcollections under its document ID.

When you create a reference to a subcollection using a document id like this:

```
db.collection('coll').doc('doc').collection('subcoll')
```

If document id `doc` doesn't already exist, that's not a problem at all.  In fact, after adding documents to `subcoll`, `doc` will appear in the Firebase console *in italics*, indicating that it doesn't exist.  There is still an opportunity to create the document, if you wish, but there is no obligation to do so.  You can reach into the contents of the subcollection whether or not the document exists.  If you create the document, you can also delete it, and all of its subcollections will still exist.

If this organization of subcollections suits your needs, feel free to use it.

Comment: is that solution still valid?

Comment: Im trying to make this but in Firestore console I cant create an empty document @Doug

Comment: Is there a name for this 'ghost' document?

Comment: @daCoda there is no formal name.

Answer (score 0):

as like all have answered u can't.
but u can make 1 doc under any collection OR 1 collection under any doc to reach the data in the way u want....
just need a longer code. e.g.-

db.collection('coll').**doc('doc')**.collection('subcoll')

bold=='only 1 doc'

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
import { doc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const messageRef = doc(db, "rooms", "roomA", "messages", "message1");
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model